# Right positioning caret

Tags: drop-down-menu, twitter-bootstrap, caret

Following html results bad positioned caret. how can I force it to be in the same line with link text?

```
<a class="dropdown-toggle" data-toggle="dropdown" href="#">
 link text <span class="caret"></span>
</a>
```

[image]

Comment: Don't see anything wrong with the html you posted.  My guess is that the container of the anchor tag is not large enough.  Can you post the surrounding markup?

Comment: its large enough, the image is a part of 960px row